# React Native props not updating with the navigator

Tags: react-native, navigator

I am passing props and a function to the second page of the navigator as follows:

```
  unlock: function(object) {
  switch(true) {
  case (object==0): this.setState({a: false});break;
  case (object==1): this.setState({b: false});break;
  case (object==2): this.setState({c: false});break;
  case (object==3): this.setState({d: false});break;
  default: this.setState({e: false});break;}
  },
```

Then pass props through the navigator:

```
 this.props.navigator.push({
        title: title,
        component: component,
        passProps: {unlock: this.unlock,a: this.state.a, b:       this.state.b,c: this.state.c,d: this.state.d, e: this.state.e}
    });
```

But when I call the function in the second navigator page it updates ok but only to the home page. The information within this second navigator page does not update while I remain on the page. So for example this code:

```
 <Text>{this.props.a}</Text?
```

Still shows the value prior to activating the function while in the second page. I have to go back to the main page and then return once more to the second page to see the updated value. This only seems to happen with the navigator. With any other method it updates instantly.

The only workaround I had was to both set state within the second page as well as setting props for the home page. It seems a bit of an unnecessary workaround though.

Comment: If you need to share state between components I would suggest using a flux container like alt js. http://alt.js.org/, I had the same problem the flux container fixed it for me.

Comment: Are u using React.createClass or React.Component? And did you define any PropTypes?

Comment: No I haven't done anything special, I thought this was just normal functionality. its React.createClass. Its simply updating a value using a passed function like this.props.unlock on the second navigator page. But the referred value does not change until going back to the home page and then returning to the second page again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you call the unlock function in next component? Until you call it, it will not set the state of that main component, since unlock function is in main component it will only be called on main component , i think that your problem.

Comment: Yes as stated in my description: "But when I call the function in the second navigator page..."